# Serializing an array of arrays in java using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm learning how to use Jackson and I have to serialize an array of ContoCorrente objects

```
public class ContoCorrente {
    private String proprietario;
    private ArrayList<MovimentoBancario> movimenti;
//methods...
}
```

where MovimentoBancario is defined as

```
public class MovimentoBancario {
    private String data;
    private String causale;
//methods...
}
```

I tried with

```
ArrayList<ContoCorrente> conti= new ArrayList<ContoCorrente>(50);
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
            //fill array
        }
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
            System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(conti));  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but the output is

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, it's the first time I try serialization

Comment: It's not your serialization that's the problem, it's either that you're not actually putting things into the array or that your class definitions are wrong. Show more code.

Comment: I'm sure that I'm filling the array correctly, but what do you mean when you say that class definitions may be wrong?

Comment: You may be sure, but we aren't. You didn't show either `//fill array` or the definition of `ContoCorrente`.

Comment: By default, Jackson won't serialize private fields. Do you have public getter/setter methods for the fields you want to serialize?

Comment: @dnault that was the problem, I totally missed that, now I added getter methods and it works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining a specific method using Jackson.

```
private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
private static final ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(Array.class);


public static String toArray(ArrayList<ContoCorrente> array) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(array);
}
```

Then if you want to read just use the reader.